# Timestamp fields in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a MySQL database, right now I'm generating all of the datetime fields as `models.DateTimeField`. Is there a way to get a `timestamp` instead? I want to be able to autoupdate on create and update etc.

The documentation on django doesn't have this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There was actually a very good and informative article on this. Here:
http://ianrolfe.livejournal.com/36017.html

The solution on the page is slightly deprecated, so I did the following:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime

class UnixTimestampField(models.DateTimeField):
    """UnixTimestampField: creates a DateTimeField that is represented on the
    database as a TIMESTAMP field rather than the usual DATETIME field.
    """
    def __init__(self, null=False, blank=False, **kwargs):
        super(UnixTimestampField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # default for TIMESTAMP is NOT NULL unlike most fields, so we have to
        # cheat a little:
        self.blank, self.isnull = blank, null
        self.null = True # To prevent the framework from shoving in "not null".

    def db_type(self, connection):
        typ=['TIMESTAMP']
        # See above!
        if self.isnull:
            typ += ['NULL']
        if self.auto_created:
            typ += ['default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP']
        return ' '.join(typ)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(value)
        else:
            return models.DateTimeField.to_python(self, value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if value==None:
            return None
        # Use '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' for MySQL < 4.1
        return strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',value.timetuple())
```

To use it, all you have to do is:
    `timestamp = UnixTimestampField(auto_created=True)`

In MySQL, the column should appear as:
    `'timestamp' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`

Only drawback with this is that it only works on MySQL databases. But you can easily modify it for others.

Comment: The `get_db_prep_value` function is out of date, as it only applies to `TIMESTAMP` columns on MySQL < 4.1. For modern versions of MySQL use `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` instead of `'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`.

Comment: For django 1.8 you should implement from_db_value to convert the database value to your object's attribute.

Answer (score 4):

To automatically update on insert and update use this:

```
created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
last_modified = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
```

The DateTimeField should store UTC (check your DB settings, I know from Postgres that there it is the case). You can use `l10n` in the templates and format via:

```
{{ object.created|date:'SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT' }}
```

Seconds since Unix Epoch:

```
{{ object.created|date:'U' }}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score 3):

The pip package django-unixdatetimefield provides a UnixDateTimeField field that you can use for this out of the box (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-unixdatetimefield/).

Example model:

```
from django_unixdatetimefield import UnixDateTimeField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_at = UnixDateTimeField()
```

Python ORM query:

```
>>> m = MyModel()
>>> m.created_at = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 21, 19, 38, 32, 209148)
>>> m.save()
```

Database:

```
sqlite> select created_at from mymodel;
1426967129
```

Here's the source code if interested - https://github.com/Niklas9/django-unixdatetimefield.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this pip package.

Comment: does it have options for __NULL__ etc?

Comment: it does, it subclasses the standard DateTimeField in Django, which in turn supports NULL etc. See code line 8 at - https://github.com/Niklas9/django-unixdatetimefield/blob/master/django_unixdatetimefield/fields.py

Comment: I am trying to insert data from Django Rest Framework, and when I send the payload: { "timeStamp": 1581950810, }

I get this error: { "timeStamp": [ "Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]." ] }

Is it possible to accept timestamp on the field?

Comment: You're using it the wrong way. If you need to send unix timestamps to your API, you should use Django Rest Framework to handle it, no need to use this library.

Answer (score 0):

[django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/) has a useful `TimeStampedModel`: https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_extensions.html

Comment: That just uses `DateTimeField` to add `created `and `modified` fields.